# Можно ли из C++/CLR подключить либу на Си?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, компоновщик

Пишу приложение на C++/CLR. Пытаюсь подключить Си-библиотеку - начинаются проблемы с компиляцией. Как я понимаю, C++/CLR и Си не дружат, что очень странно. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Код ошибки:

> Error LNK2028 unresolved token (0A000874) "extern "C" int __cdecl
>   MQTTClient_create(void * *,char const *,char const *,int,void *)"
>   (?MQTTClient_create@@$$J0YAHPAPAXPBD1HPAX@Z) referenced in function
>   "void __cdecl myfunc(void)" (?myfunc@@$$FYAXXZ)   opc_mqtt

В линкере:

> /OUT:"C:\projects\vcpp\opc_mqtt\Debug\test_c_lib_clr.exe" /MANIFEST
>   /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\projects\vcpp\opc_mqtt\Debug\test_c_lib_clr.pdb"
>   /DYNAMICBASE "paho-mqtt3a.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib"
>   "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib"
>   "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG
>   /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL
>   /PGD:"C:\projects\vcpp\opc_mqtt\Debug\test_c_lib_clr.pgd"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /ManifestFile:"Debug\test_c_lib_clr.exe.intermediate.manifest"
>   /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\mqtt\paho-c\lib" /TLBID:1

Comment: а какую ошибку выдаёт? Добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: А разве в C++  нет чего то полезного из С?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, библиотек.

Comment: а как вы их подключаете?

Comment: В настройках проекта

Comment: Сейчас создал пустой проект консольный проект на С++, изменил ему на Common Language RunTime Support (/clr)... такая же ошибка при линковке библиотеки..

Comment: Судя по сигнатуре это не Си имя.  Должно быть, что то типа _MQTTClient_create. Возможно Вы забыли extern "C" { #include "header.h" } .

Comment: По виду ошибки как будто просто не подключен нужный lib-файл. Покажите код и параметры компоновщика (Свойства проекта - Linker - Command line).

Comment: Прописал в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не связана напрямую с C++/CLI. Вы подключаете библиотеку paho-mqtt3a (asynchronous MQTT), а используете при этом функцию MQTTClient_create из библиотеки paho-mqtt3c (classic MQTT). Добавьте в параметры компоновщика **paho-mqtt3c.lib**, и все заработает.

---

А на вопрос "*Можно ли из C++/CLR подключить либу на Си?*" ответ, разумеется, "да". Есть только одна маленькая деталь: при сборке с параметром /clr:pure или /clr:safe соглашение вызова по умолчанию будет clrcall, а не cdecl, поэтому все объявления функции без явного указания соглашения о вызове не будут работать. При сборке с параметром просто /clr этой проблемы нет.